# Power Query - Replace negative numbers with zero

Tags: replace, powerquery

Any chance I can replace the negative numbers in a column with zero, in Power Query. I was looking all over the internet, couldn't find an answer...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the column, transform .. absolute value

edit the end of the code from something that looks like this

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStep",{{"Column1", Number.Abs, type number}})
```

to look like this

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStep",{{"Column1", each if _ < 0 then 0 else _ , type number}})
```